# sonarqube:SonarQube Scanner 2.3 for Visual Studio 2017 Builds

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan

one of our feature teams who is using SonarQube since long and they are now getting issues when they upgrade to VS 2017,To support SonarQube for scanning in VSTS build, we need the task updated with SonarQube 2.3 or higher to support along with VS 2017 for code analysis. May I know is there any work going on this when can we get the support for VS 2017?

Comment: You should probably post this at VS' support forum/page.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SonarQube extension in VSTS, you can install [SonarQube 3.0.2 version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube). (You need to update SonarQube extension if old version has already been installed in manage/admin extension page of you VSTS. `https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_extensions`)

After that, you can change `3.*` version of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild task in build or release.